# SQL Latest Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an interesting bit of logic that I can't seem to get my head around.

We have a Purchase table, where each Purchase is linked to a Customer and a Date. We want to pull out the Purchase that each customer made closest to the end of each month.

For instance,

```
CustomerID   |  Date
1            |  01/20/2009
2            |  01/26/2009
1            |  01/21/2009
1            |  02/02/2009
```

Should return....

```
CustomerID   |  Date
2            |  01/26/2009
1            |  01/21/2009
1            |  02/02/2009
```

Any ideas for a simple way to do this using SQL Server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT  CustomerID, MAX(Date)
FROM    Purchase
GROUP BY CustomerID, YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CustomerID, MAX(Date)
FROM Purchases
GROUP BY CustomerID, MONTH(Date), YEAR(Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by the customer id and the year and date components of the date, and use the max aggregate to get the latest date from each group:

```
select CustomerId, max(Date)
from Purchase
group by CustomerId, datepart(year, Date), datepart(month, Date)
```

Note: If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use the `year` and `month` functions instead of `datepart`.

Answer (score 0):

Group by month,year
having max(day)